# Why is there disparity between Google Analytics Events and Campaign Goals?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I have an event that fires when a form is submitted, which is triggered by `ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submit', 'inquiry form');`.

In Google Analytics (GA) under Behavior->Events I am able to see that this event has been triggered 36 times in the past month.

In the Admin section for that same Site I have set up a Goal to match: http://cl.ly/image/1v010P2s1R0b

However, when I go to Acquisition->Campaigns, that goal is only registered as having happened 3 times within the same time period: http://cl.ly/image/1C2P1D1G3e1k

Why is this the case? Shouldn't it have 36 completions registered? Are they somehow measuring different things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goals are only counted once per session. [This table](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2679221?hl=en) may be helpful.

As long as you are still using event tracking, you will be able to get the total number of events, regardless of the number of sessions.

Comment: Ah, OK, so the Goals are only reached when someone has come to the site  by clicking an Ad (and submitted the form), whereas the events will happen however someone reaches the site (and submits the form). That makes sense. Thanks!